# How to separate digits from characters using regular expression?

Tags: regex

I have a set of string which needs to sepearate them in the groups of expresions:

```
43M ---> 43 and M

57F ---> 57 and F

39CD/TV ---> 39 and CD/TV
```

I have suggested the pattern such as `(\d)+(\w).` but it does not work for the last case `CD/TV`.

What is the proper pattern to do it?

Comment: Use `(\d+)(\D*)`

Comment: in java it complains with `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

Comment: In Java string use: `(\\d+)(\\D*)`

Comment: @KamyarParastesh Strange, didn't your `(\d)+(\w)` complain of the same? Please provide the exact requirements for the strings you need to match.

Answer (score 0):

just replace

```
\b(\d+)
```

with

```
(capture group) and
```

see the demo here [demo](https://regex101.com/r/BwNvsv/2)

if incase you want to capture both groups here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/BwNvsv/3)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [Regex example](https://regex101.com/r/UgnSxo/1). It will give you two groups, one for the number part and another for the string part.

Regex: `(\d+)+(\w.*)`